# Return 2 rows per user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm needing to return the latest 2 rows in a table for each user that matches a bunch of criteria.

So for example, "Get me the latest 2 rows from the products table, where user the user status is not pending, and the user has been registered longer than a week".

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this. If it was one row per user it would be simple. Likewise if i could dump the results out and do further filtering in my PHP code, i could get it working that way (however i need LIMIT pagination, so it needs to all be in a query).

I've set up a very simplified table with some data in it, just for ease of working it out, which you can see here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b32d2

Essentially, the solution query, will return two rows maximum per "owner_id", and the two rows returned will be the 2 highest dates from the "added" column.

Hopefully that makes sense, and thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Do u have sample data?is it like this `SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY owner_id HAVING COUNT(*)>2`

Comment: I posted a fiddle? Nevermind i found the answer just after posting this (always happens, takes me ages to work something out, the minute i ask for help, i find the solution!)

Comment: Can you link to whichever answer you found? Hopefully it's faster  than mine.

Comment: Hi Dan, its exactly the same! Got it from here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ ... Although if anyone does have a more performant solution it would be great. I now nee to test this inside a more complex query on my real data of 500k rows... this could go slightly bad

Answer (score 3):

This is monstrously inefficient, but it works.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` p1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `products` p2 
    WHERE p2.added > p1.added
      AND p2.owner_id = p1.owner_id
    ) < 2
```

Comment: This is the solution i just worked out using some blog post linked on another SO question. For now it will do, i need to implement caching anyway, if it gets really bad, i'll have to restructure the database (or worse, keep a secondary table for this particular lookup which only has the latest 2 products per user in it)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   P2.ID,
   IF (@PREVIOUS_OWNER = P2.OWNER_ID, 
     @CURRANK := @CURRANK + 1, 
     @CURRANK := 1) AS RANK,
   (@PREVIOUS_OWNER := P2.OWNER_ID) AS OWNER_ID,
   P2.ADDED
  FROM PRODUCTS P2, (SELECT @CURRANK := -1, @PREVIOUS_OWNER := -1) R
  ORDER BY P2.OWNER_ID, P2.ADDED DESC
  ) P
WHERE P.RANK <= 2
```

What is this query doing?

- It sorts the results according to the `owner_id` and `date`
- It declares two variables `CURRANK` and `PREVIOUS_OWNER`
- `PREVIOUS_OWNER` will be evaluated to the current `OWNER_ID` **after** `CURRANK` has been calculated which means that inside the `IF` statement `PREVIOUS_OWNER` will be **-1** for the first row, and the **previous row** `OWNER_ID` for every other row
- Last but not least, if the `PREVIOUS_OWNER` is the same as the current `OWNER_ID` then we increment `CURRANK`, else we reset it to 1 (if clause) so that we can simulate partition by `OWNER_ID`

So the inner query will rank every product from the same owner according to `ADDED`. The rank is aliased to `RANK`.

The outer query filters `RANK` less than or equal to 2.

This is kinda funk code but supposedly performs better than the `COUNT(*)` counterpart if you create a index for `OWNER_ID` and `ADDED`.

Anyway we are pushing the edges of what MySQL is supposed to do and creating a potentially huge in memory table (`P`) in order to extract a couple of rows per `OWNER_ID`, so this is neither beautiful nor recommended. Still, to the best of my knowledge, this is as good as it gets until MySQL starts supporting Analytic Functions or `LIMIT` clauses in subqueries.

---

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b32d2/83)

Comment: Thanks Anthony, i'll give this whirl later on. As i said my table structure is a little more complex (i need to join and use MAX(added) for a start), but i didnt want to over complicate teh question with my table structures. I may have to de-normalise some of my data structure to make things workable, and i'm toying with the idea of using a seperate table or redis instance to hold some queryable information which will produce just a list of id's to lookup in my primary mysql store... but i'll see where i get too. Agile development has its drawbacks when people request things like this!

Comment: Lee no problem. To be fair MySQL manual contains a pretty scary warning about defining and assigning variables in the same statement [check out MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement."

Comment: Still, I can guarantee that any problem that can be solved with the count approach can be solved with this approach... Also, I've been running queries like these over huge datasets for several years without issues (the disadvantages of non Agile workshops is that is harder to make them swallow NoSQL solutions hehehe).